# Selecting column from LINQ query where cells equals value from a list

Tags: c#, linq, compare, observablecollection

I added data to an ObservableCollection from a LINQ query:

```
foreach (var item in test4)
{
   lstPareto.Add(new clsPareto(Convert.ToInt32(item.Step), Convert.ToInt32(item.LogID), test3.Where(p => p.Step.Equals(item.Step) && p.LogID.Equals(item.LogID)).Count()));
}
```

And this works fine. I get the items I want and convert them to an int when adding them to the list.

Then I have the following queries that pulls data from multiple databases:

```
int intCmbTestNr = Convert.ToInt32(m_strCmbTestNrSelectedItem);

var productIndex = (from x in m_dcSQL_ConnectionProdTest.DC3_VersionReleases
                    where x.TestNumber.Equals(intCmbTestNr)
                    select x.ProductIndex).First();

var version = ((from y in m_dcSQL_ConnectionProdTest.DC3_MainSetups
                where y.ProductIndex == productIndex && y.SubVersion == 0
                select y.Version).Max());

var versionIndex = (from z in m_dcSQL_ConnectionProdTest.DC3_MainSetups
                    where z.ProductIndex == productIndex && z.Version.Equals(version) && z.SubVersion == 0
                    select z.VersionIndex).First();

var subFuncName = from a in m_dcSQL_ConnectionProdTest.DC3_SubFunctions
                  where a.VersionIndex == versionIndex && a.FunctionNumber == lstPareto.Select(b => b.intStep) && a.SubFunctionNumber == lstPareto.Select(c => c.intStep)
                  select a.SubFunctionName;
```

Consider subFuncName. What I am trying to achieve here is to compare a.FunctionNumber to intStep and a.SubFunctionNumber to intLogID of the list lstPareto. However, it says the following: "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type'int' and 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable". I think I know the reason for this, seeing as I'm trying to compare a single int to a whole collection. But how do I compare to every single item intStep and intLogID of the list? I cannot seem to wrap my head around this. Do I use a foreach loop somewhere? Can somebody get me back on track?

Sorry if the title is somewhat vague, couldn't really think of a good one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both `FunctionNumber` and `SubFunctionNumber` is `int`:s. Then you can change the condition to this:

```
lstPareto.Select(b => b.intStep).Contains(a.FunctionNumber) 
&&  lstPareto.Select(c => c.intStep).Contains(a.SubFunctionNumber)
```

**Update**

The reason is most probably because you do not have `.ToList()`, `.First()`, `.Single()` in the query. Depends a little bit what you expect. You could change it to this:

```
var subFuncName = (from a in m_dcSQL_ConnectionProdTest.DC3_SubFunctions
                  where a.VersionIndex == versionIndex && lstPareto.Select(b => b.intStep).Contains(a.FunctionNumber) 
                  &&  lstPareto.Select(c => c.intStep).Contains(a.SubFunctionNumber)
                  select a.SubFunctionName).ToList();
```

Reference:

- [Enumerable.Contains Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains(v=vs.100).ASPX)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, and it did solve the initial problem. However, a new problem arose. If I do a debug and set break points at each query, the first 3 gets the correct values. The 4th one does not get anything and says it's a DataQuery<string>. If I expand the results view to see what the query outputs it says the following:

"Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation."

Comment: Hmm looks like this isn't really a problem, since I can add the functionnames to a list just fine. The only problem is seeing what the variable contains WHILE debugging, and why this happens I have no idea.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't see your comment before posting. I just tried adding ToList() but it still says the evalution thing.